# Exclude from output if column has any entry other than xyz

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to output rows where Zipcodes have entries of ONLY category `a` - e.g. on the table below:

```
Id | Category | Name | ZipCode | Extraneous
--------------------------------------------
1      a         Jim    1234      a comment
2      a         Jim    1234      other
3      b         Jim    1234      no way
4      a         Baz    5678      foobar
5      c         Gil    0000      jiminy
6      a         Amy    0000      wibble
```

I should only be getting row 4. I don't want zipcode `1234` to show even if it has an `a` entry, because it also has an entry for category `b` - similar with Zipcode `0000` has an entry for `c` so shouldn't be shown.

So far I'm doing:

```
select max(t1.Id),
    t1.Category,
    t1.Name,
    t1.ZipCode,
    t1.Extraneous
from tbl t1
join tbl t2 on t1.Zipcode = t2.Zipcode
where t1.Category = 'a'
and t2.Category != 'b' and t2.Category != 'c'
group by
    t1.Category,
    t1.Name,
    t1.ZipCode,
    t1.Extraneous
```

Which still gives results for ZipCode 1234

How do I get all instances of a ZipCode which have entries for `b` but only if they have no other category entries?

Comment: `select distinct` is not needed here, your `GROUP BY` will not return any duplicates.

Comment: @jarlh thanks for the tip - I'll remove that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using not exists:

```
select
a.*

from
table1 a
where not exists (select zipcode from table1 b where a.zipcode = b.zipcode and b.category <> 'A')
and a.category = 'A'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from tbl t
where not exists (select 1
                  from tbl t2
                  where t2.zipcode = t.zipcode and t2.category <> 'A'
                 );
```

You can also use window functions.  For instance:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
            sum(case when category = 'a' then 0 else 1 end)
            over (partition by zipcode) as cnt_nota
     from tbl t
    ) t
where cnt_nota = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks as always, Gordon. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Can use except..

```
    select zipcode
    from table1
    where category = 'a'
    except
    select zipcode
    from table1
    where category <> 'a'
```

Comment: This just brings out the zipcode, not the entire row of data, as soon as I add other columns to the selects it brings out the other rows again.

Comment: I misread the question, sorry. Didn't notice "all rows". Looks like you already have an answer so I won't bother correcting this.